# How to speed up JavaScript image loading

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch, service-worker

I have a website that needs to load 10 images at page load. However, I need to perform a few operations on the images before they're inserted into the `DOM`.

When I load the images using `fetch` **without** even preforming any operations then I insert them into the page, the page takes multiple times longer to load than it does when I test using the same images but placing them into an `<img src=="url"` tag. I understand that this is because JavaScript is single-threaded and browser load HTML much faster than JS. But what can I do to speed up retrieving the images using `fetch`?
Example:

```
for (let i =0; i < 10; i++) {
    const imageBlob = await fetch('https://picsum.photos/300/200').then(response => response.blob());
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')';

}
```

I know using Service Workers might be helpful for caching the `fetch` request, but what is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: What's the point? You can just `imageElement.src = 'url.png';`, after performing operations. You can even create the `imageElement` dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure your server uses HTTP/2 to offer faster downloading.  Then, you can process each image response asynchronously for better performance.

```
const images = [...]

Promise.all(images.map(url => fetch(url).then(processImageResponse))
  .then(allImagesProcessed)

async function processImageResponse(response) {
  // consider ArrayBuffer here instead: response.arrayBuffer()
  const blob = await response.blob();
  ...
}

// receives results[] of what each processImageResponse() returns
function allImagesProcessed(results) {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can download the image locally on the server/website on, hence:

```
const imageBlob = await fetch('./images/200.jpg').then(response => response.blob());
```

This will increase the speed as it won't need to attempt to fetch from an external source.

Comment: I need to perform the operation on the front-end.